# Removing a column in a pandas dataframe if all the values are a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe called df.

Sometimes it looks like this (where each value is unique)

```
   key   value1 value2 value3
0  key1  value  value  value
1  key2  value  value  value
```

Sometimes the entire column of `value3` are is filled with dashes: `'-'`.

```
   key   value1 value2 value3
0  key1  value  value  -
1  key2  value  value  -
```

I want to find a command which will drop the column value3 if all the items in the column dashes.

I tried using `df['value3'].any()` and that that returns a `'-'`.

Is the right way to do what I want this?

```
if df['value3'].any() == '-':
    df = df.drop['value3']
```

Or is there a better way?

Comment: no it's rather `if (df['value3'] == '-').all(): df = df.drop('value3', axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare for not equal by [`DataFrame.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ne.html) and then get all columns with match by [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.allanyhtml) in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df.loc[:, df.ne('-').any()])
    key value1 value2
0  key1  value  value
1  key2  value  value
```

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
>>> df.loc[:, ~df.eq('-').all()]
    key value1 value2
0  key1  value  value
1  key2  value  value
```